# How to read JSON value by passing Keys?

Tags: json, angular, angular-forms

I have the following code snippet of JSON. I want to assign these values to 3 inputs respectively. Please assist me with proper code

```
[
{
"id":210,
"Title":"Resource Manager",
"Name":"James",
"Email":"DJames@company.com"
     
}
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first convert the json to javascript object if it is not converted yet, skip this step if already done by you or angular

```
const object = JSON.parse(json);
```

now you access the different value of property of javascript object like this

```
let valueOfTitle = object['Title'];
let name = object['Name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const val = [
{
"id":210,
"Title":"Resource Manager",
"Name":"James",
"Email":"DJames@company.com"
     
}
];

const email = val[0].Email;
const name = val[0].Name;
const title = val[0].Title;
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks Ahmad.